# j2objc: No such file or directory

Tags: j2objc

I was including the j2objc library file in objective c program.  I mean I was translating the java code into objective c. But when I run, the project  error occurs as j2objc: No such file or directory can someone help me with how to initialize the j2objc library in objective c project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got answer   initially download the j2objc library file and  drag the  bin folder in ur system like as  Users/username/bin/j2objc library file .after that clean the project and run the project  working for me .